# Timeout in implicit Wolfram|Alpha calls, but WolframAlpha works

Tags: units, wolfram-alpha-queries, entity

In general we expect this to work:

```
Quantity["Speed of light"]

Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"]
```

And it does because it can make use of Wolfram|Alpha.

Oddly, though, when at work this will *always* timeout for me. The same happens with `Entity` when trying to format.

We can replicate it like so:

```
Block[{WolframAlphaClient`Private`$AlphaQueryTimeConstraint = .1},
 Quantity[1, "Speed of light"]
 ]
```

> ```
> EntityValue::timeout: A network operation for EntityValue timed out. Please try again later.
>
> Quantity::unkunit: Unable to interpret unit specification a.
> ```

```
Quantity[1, "Speed of light"]
```

Despite that, this does work:

```
WolframAlpha["speed of light", "Result"]

Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"]
```

One thing I have noticed is that in my Terminal my [hostname](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#HOSTNAMEREF) is reassigned to a UUID-like string rather than the standard human-readable one Macs provide.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?